# Difference between class and package

Tags: java

What is the difference between a class and a package in Java ?

Comment: They have very little in common. The question is unmotivated and basically meaningless. A package is a container for related classes.

Comment: It really helps when you do some research on your own prior to asking here. Typically, we're happy to answer basic questions as long as documentation that can be found on the web is not of good quality. That, however is not the case here. I'm not closing it, because it is a _real_ question that is on topic.

Comment: @Tim: Though I agree that this is a real question and is on topic, but still I consider that before asking something here, some homework must be done.

Comment: @Logan - I don't disagree with you, but I did feel obligated to explain my lack of action given the number of flags that were raised on this question. Remember, my vote is binding, so I'm leaving this up to the community.

Answer (score 20):

A [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) is a declaration (and often implementation) which [encapsulates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) the members properties and methods which instances of that type will posses.  You can create instances of a class as distinct, individual objects that behave as specified.

A [package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) is simply a [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) under which you can categorize classes, analogous to a "folder" or "path", so you can group classes with related purpose or functionality.

Don't be confused by the fact that Java has classes which represent both the concept of a [Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and a [Package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html) which are useful for inspecting the structure of Java programs at runtime.  They are merely models of the general concepts described above.

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply a [java package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) is a namespace where classes are organized based on the same category or functionality

Java classes is an object that consists of behaviours (methods), properties (variables), constructors (if any, for object creation), etc. that exists inside a folder (package).

Answer (score 2):

A class is like a Template,  where an you put set `Behaviors (Methods)` and `properties (Instance variables)` which every Object of its kind will Posses.

but package is totally different and has nothing to do with technical part. It is just for the purpose of Readability and Organizing your code. you have to put classes with different behaviour in diff package. thats it.

Answer (score 2):

For understanding it more clearly,just think a package as a box of toolset. You have various tools in a toolset box i.e a screw driver,cutter,cutting pliers etc. Each tool set box is a package which is collection of various tools ( classes). Now here each tool ie a screw driver is a class , cutter another class etc, each of tool having their own properties and purpose ( operation).In the similar way you have many toolsets designed for domestic,industrial purposes which can be compared to different packages.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Package is a mechanism for organizing Java classes into namespaces. Java packages can be stored in compressed files called JAR files, allowing classes to download faster as a group rather than one at a time.

on the other hand, a class is a programming language construct that is used to group related instance variables and methods. Each class expresses structural and behavioral design decisions made by the programmer to indicate what types of objects can exist when the program is executed.

Reference: [Coders2020](http://www.coders2020.com/what-is-a-class-and-package-in-java-explain-difference-between-them)